# getting percentage from custom attribute value with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML:

```
  <li class="project" data-project="300">web template 300 </li>
  <li class="project" data-project="200">wordpress 200 </li>
  <li class="project" data-project="160">graphic design 160 </li>
```

Is it possible to get values from the `data-project` attribute and get the sum. And then getting a percentage with JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = 0;
    $('.project').each(function(){
        a = a + parseInt($(this).data('project'));
    })
    console.log(a);
});`

Please try this...

Comment: Thanks, It gets the total value from all attributes. Is it possible to get the individual percentages?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get custom attribute value using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = 0;
    $('li').each(function(){
        a = a + parseInt($(this).attr('data-project'));
    })
    console.log(a);
})
```